# Android App Autocomplete using values in Database

Tags: android, sqlite, autocomplete, textbox

I am developing android app where user will be searching words to get other information. I want to give autocomplete facility.
There will be 5000+ words that user can search from. So I do not want to keep them in memory in an array. As this will unnecessary eat a lot memory.
I will store all the words in a Database(SQLite DB) table column.

How can I implement auto-complete in this scenario? 
So as soon as user enters a character at least 10 words starting with that character should appear. As user keeps typing that exact starting sequence should be considered for suggestions.

Is there default Android API for such autocomplete for values from DB ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a facility named auto complete

```
        adapter = new InviteUsersAdapter(getActivity(), input);
        autocompletetextview.setThreshold(3);
        autocompletetextview.setAdapter(adapter);
        autocompletetextview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

In this you have to manually define the adapter and declare auto complete as

```
private AutoCompleteTextView autocompletetextview;
```

and you can set threshold to any value you want to.I think this would help you.